# How to return specific JSON data by an ID parameter in Golang server

Tags: json, http, go, gorilla

I am working on a project I've tasked to myself.

I'm trying to set up a Golang server that displays JSON data from a remote json file based on a parameter (ID) passed by the user.

I can find plenty of guides that show how to consume ALL the data from the json API, but I don't know how to pass a parameter to the function so it only returns the required data.

Here is what I have so far:

Setting up the basic server and routes

```
func main() {

    //Initialises basic router and endpoints
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", home).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/games/all", getAll).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/games/{id}", getGame).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/games/report", getReport).Methods("GET")

    fmt.Println("Listening on port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

}
```

This is my getAll method that sends the GET request (Using the pokedex api for now until i host my json file).

```
func getAll(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    response, err := http.Get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/kanto/")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(responseData))
}
```

Have also built the structs for the data. But i cant, for the life of me, find a way to pass the parameter to do the getGame method to handle that route. Please, if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you looking to get to the `{id}` parameter?

Comment: Yes. Looking to return Json entries that match the {id}

Comment: I guess you are using the gorilla mux.  Use `vars := mux.Vars(r)` and then vars["id"] and read the examples https://github.com/gorilla/mux

Comment: Yes using the mux package. I managed to get that part out of some guides @georgeok but how would i apply the vars to the url to only return the entries with the matching id

Comment: If I get it correctly you want to use the ID instead of the name. So replace `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/kanto/` with `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/2`

Comment: I want localhost:8080/games/1 to return entry number 1, and localhost:8080/games/2 to return entry number 2, as per the router.